# Control DC Motor Speed with an AVR 8-bit Microcontroller

Tags: c, avr, atmega

I'm trying to control DC motor speed. As of right now, to my limited understanding, I suppose I'm able to control the motor with just high and low by setting and clearing bits. The goal is to have the motor run at its 50% or 70% of the max speed, preferrably while gradually increasing and decreasing the speed. Please see the following piece of code and the circuit diagram for the current system configuration.

Here's the motor's datasheet:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8801.pdf

The board I'm using is:

ATmega64A
Atmel AVR 8-bit Microcontroller

[image]

```c
#define MOTOR_CON           PORTA

#define DC_ENABLE_ON        sbi(PORTA, 3)
#define DC_ENABLE_OFF       cbi(PORTA, 3)

#define DC_PHASE_ON         sbi(PORTA, 2)
#define DC_PHASE_OFF        cbi(PORTA, 2)

#define DC_MODE_ON          sbi(PORTA, 1)
#define DC_MODE_OFF         cbi(PORTA, 1)
    
void MotorSpeedSwingUp(void)
{
    DC_ENABLE_ON;
}

void MotorSpeedSwingDn(void)
{
    DC_ENABLE_OFF;
}

void MotorForwardPhase(void)
{
    DC_PHASE_ON;
    DC_MODE_OFF;
}

void MotorReversePhase(void)
{
    DC_PHASE_OFF;
    DC_MODE_OFF;
}

void MotorRun(void)
{
    if(motor_swing_flag == TRUE)
    {
        motor_swing_flag = FALSE;
        MotorSpeedSwingUp();
    }
    else
    {
        motor_swing_flag = TRUE;
        MotorSpeedSwingDn();
    }
}

void MotorBrake(void)
{
    DC_PHASE_OFF;//Forward
    DC_ENABLE_OFF;
    DC_MODE_ON;
}
```

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: Seems like the important part of the datasheet is `9.2.3.1 Pulse Width Modulating ENABLE` - "The most common H-Bridge direction/speed control scheme is to use a conventional GPIO output for the
PHASE (selects direction) and pulse-width modulate ENABLE for speed control." Sooooo, 50% duty cycle for 50% speed and 70% duty-cycle for 70% speed.

Comment: would you be able to provide a brief code or pseudo code please? I'm completely new to embedded programming..

Comment: you might want to read: [dc motor controller](https://www.integrasources.com/blog/dc-motor-controller-design-principles/)   and [dc torque motor controller](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/86517-build-a-dc-motor-speed-controller-circuit/)   Note that a DC motor controller can consume a huge amount of current so plan accordinngly

Comment: A brief glance at the datasheet shows that the ATmega64A does have timers that can generate PWM signals.  Using the timers to generate PWM signals is great because the AVR's hardware will take care of generating the signal in the background for you while the CPU is free to do other tasks.  So why are you trying to generate a PWM signal manually using general-purpose I/O?  Read about the timers in the datasheet and search for things like "ATmega64A PWM example code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of PWM control is to repeat ON and OFF in a very
short cycle as shown in Figure 9-3 and so on. The ratio of ON time
in the cycle is called "duty cycle" and is proportional to the motor
rotation speed as enhzflep comments.

Let's suppose the cycle is 200usec and we want to have the motor
rotate at 70% speed. Then we should repeat the following sequence:

- Enable the motor.
- Wait 140usec.
- Disable the motor.
- Wait 60usec.

Assuming your C compiler supports `usleep()` function, would you please
try something like (not tested):

```
#define CYCLE 200       // 200usec for 1 cycle
#include <unistd.h>

/*
 * have the motor run at "duty" speed for "duration" seconds
 * 0.0 <= duty <= 1.0
 */
void PwmRun(double duty, int duration)
{
    if (duty < 0.) duty = 0.;                   // lower limit of "duty"
    if (duty > 1.) duty = 1.;                   // upper limit of "duty"

    int ontime = (int)(CYCLE * duty);           // PWM on time
    int offtime = (int)(CYCLE * (1. - duty));   // PWM off time

    for (int t = 0; t < duration * 1000000; t += CYCLE) {
        if (ontime > 0) DC_ENABLE_ON;
        usleep(ontime);
        if (offtime > 0) DC_ENABLE_OFF;
        usleep(offtime);
    }
}

// example to run the motor at 70% speed for 3 seconds
PwmRun(0.7, 3);
```

It will be easy to modify the code to gradually increase the speed
from 50% to 70%.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. Unfortunately though :( I need to be running the motor until a certain condition is satisfied and I do not know how long it takes until the condition's met. Would you be able to revise the code such that the motor runs in a PWM fashion whenever it's running instead of running in PWM for a certain duration please?

Comment: The reason why I've added a parameter `duration` is because otherwise the `PwmRun()`
function does not return. If you can stop the function with some interrupt, you can
keep the function running on by modifying the `for` loop as `for (1) { ..`.

Comment: According to David Grayson's comment, I think I should look into how to generate a PWM signal and make use of it. I got your idea though. Thank you so much.

Comment: I do agree. If the hardware takes care of the PWM control, it will be better.